# Conditional parameters in function definition PHP

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

I would like to know, if there is any possibility to make a condition for parameters in a function definition, eg:

```
function attachFile
(
  $function_method = "standard", // just default value..
  if ( $function_method == "standard" )
  {
    $next_parameter_for_classic_method,
    // ...
  }
  else if ( $function_method == "other_method" )
  {
    $next_parameter_for_other_method,
    // ...
  }
)
{
  // work...
}
```

It would greatly simplify the work with functions (I think so at least). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make your condition right after the function header and if something isn't valid you can return false!

Comment: Use an array for a parameter.

Comment: @Downvoter leave some comment please, thanks to the others

Comment: Could anyone tell me, why is this topic so bad if it has deserved downvotes? I know, simple click is easy... explanation is difficult for some individuals obviously -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a default, but otherwise no you cannot pass in a conditional statement... You could pass in an array for the second parameter to make it easier if desired though..

```
function attachFile($function_method = "standard", $options = array())
{
  if ( $function_method == "standard" )
  {
    $next_parameter_for_classic_method = $options['next_parameter_for_classic_method '];
  }
  else if ( $function_method == "other_method" )
  {
    $next_parameter_for_other_method = $options['next_parameter_for_other_method'];
  }
}
```

Example syntax:

```
attachFile('other_method', array('next_parameter_for_other_method'=>'someParameterValue'));
```